# Youtube dl Colon in Title download error

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I compiled a recent [youtube-dl](https://github.com/phihag/youtube-dl) script on 2011.08.04.

When I try and download [Snow: Coronet Peak superb conditions](http://youtu.be/3u5cl8gZCQ0) or  [New for 2012 at Holiday World: Mammoth - World's Longest Water Coaster!](http://youtu.be/7ksNclHM9hE), it downloads 0kb of the movie and the filenames will be anything that was before the colon in the Movie Title.

I get `New for 2012 at Holiday World` instead of `New for 2012 at Holiday World: Mammoth - World's Longest Water Coaster!` and `Snow` instead of `Snow: Coronet Peak superb conditions`.

So for me any download from YouTube with a `:` in the Title will give me a 0kb file with chopped title and no extension.

Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to change the name like this:

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3u5cl8gZCQ0 -o myvideo
```

Now I dont know why is that happening to you, it works for me even without the output name changed

Comment: Thankyou Hassek, but I was using -t -b -w -c in my switches and only  changed the -t to -l -b -w -c as -t (title) has under_scores in the downloaded file name and -l literal does not. This has only happened since i changed to the Literal switch (-l). I think the Literal -l switch does not like : the colon in the movie title.

Comment: It's odd since is working for me with the -l, for some reason I don't have a -b option. I am running this on a mac, maybe it has to do with your system and not the script.

Comment: Maybe Hassek, or as you have youtube dl installed in your system and you call it from the command line in Mac, i have mine compiled into an windows executable using py2exe, then i have the url and switches called after in another commandline which downloads the file. Windows sp3 and Windows 7 is what i have been using the compiled version on... i guess under_scores in file names are ok :(

Comment: FIXED:) I Just replaced `ur'_'` coding with `ur' '`in  `simple_title = re.sub(ur'(?u)([^%s]+)' % simple_title_chars, ur'_', video_title) simple_title = simple_title.strip(ur'_')`